# How do I add product name in the url in my Vue.JS APP using Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to add product name dynamically in the url. currently it is "http://localhost:8080/product/?ID=1". I want to make it "http://localhost:8080/product/Iphone-11-Pro?ID=1"

> Here is the router-link code in the .vue file

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/product/', query: { ID: item.id }">...</router-link>
```

> Here is the vue router file

```
{
  path: "/product/",
  name: "SingleProduct",
  component: SingleProduct,
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the docs (URL: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) the example looks like this:

```
// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })
```

You have to use `router.push` and than it should work.